# IE 11 (Update Version: 11.0.24) Memory Consumption Issue

Tags: internet-explorer, memory-leaks, memory-consumption

After installing windows update, my IE version updated to 11.0.9600.18059 (Update Version: 11.0.24), and I found that its consuming too much memory, when I open 3-4 tabs and surfing 10-15 mins, memory raise up to 1300-1500 MB and I have to restart it.

So is there any solution or patch available for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many tried and error when I uninstall last windows update (Which is released on 13 Oct, 2015), my IE update version revert to 11.0.23 and issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 7):

If you're a developer landing here because your page is blowing up since the IE build on October 13th. Try adding this attribute to your HTML body tag like so: `<body spellcheck='false'></body>`

Comment: @RushayTrivedi Did manually disabling the option (Lam's answer above) help?

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this fix! I have spent two days investigating this issue!

Answer (score 5):

This is likely a problem with their spellchecker. If you disable the spellchecker it's likely you won't encounter this problem anymore with the October update.

To disable it:

1. Click on Tools (or the Gear) -> Manage add-Ons
2. Click on Spelling Correction on the left under Add-on Types
3. Uncheck Enable spelling correction at the bottom
4. Hit Close and then restart your browser

Comment: Hi Lam,
I have gone through your steps but didn't find "spelling correction" Add-on, can you please share screen shot?

Comment: Yes, I also confirm that disabling spellchecker solved the high memory usage in our case too.

Answer (score 1):

It appears MS is investigating the issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/1974240

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also confirm that disabling spellchecker solved the high memory usage in our case too.

Answer (score 0):

KB3160005 seems to have fixed the memory leak we started experiencing with KB3093983.

We do use iframes, so it may have been this part of the update that did the trick... 
3168674 Storage event isn't triggered for localStorage updates in an iFrame in Internet Explorer 11